# Обновлять кеш только определённого представления

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3

У меня есть достаточно большой проект на symfony и 2 сервере тестовый и боевой.
Так вот вся разработка ведётся на тестовом сервер и когда задачи касется FrontEnd возникает проблема в дилтельном обновлении кеша. Данный процес занимает до 5 минут, что сильно затрудняет работу.

Можно ли как то обновлять кеш только конкретной URL а не всего проетка в целом?

Comment: скорее всего нет, в доках по symfony только `php bin/console cache:clear` всего проекта

Comment: А может есть информация кокой кеш работает быстрее или какой лучше использовать в зависимости от задач. Я на оф. сайте к сожелению такой информации не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У symfony есть несколько уровней cache.

Тот cache, который вы чистите и собираете (`cache:clear`), отвечает за все уровни кэширования в symfony, то есть его нельзя выбрать, но его можно настроить.

Так же необходимо познакомится с основными моделями кэширования в symfony ([англ](http://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html), [рус](https://monsterbirth.ru/2011/08/31/http-cache/)).

Общие настройки cache лежат в *app/config*. 
Cache окружения можно отключать/включать его в файлах config_dev.yml config_prod.yml.

Cache конкретных компонентов тоже можно настраивать, например, twig можно отключить в файле `config.yml`.

Comment: Буду ознакамиливаться с информацие и после поставлю отметку.

Comment: Отключил кеширования  Twig, моя проблема решена. Теперь не приходится каждый раз перестраивать кеш при проверки изменений.

Comment: я тоже на на проекте twig выключил, если это простое api, то twig не нужен